# "mysql_service" not being recognized in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I downloaded the mysql cookbook from opscode, created a recipe for adding mysql, but the provision fails here:

> ```
> NoMethodError
> -------------
> No resource or method named `mysql_service' for `Chef::Recipe "default"'
>
> 13:  
> 14>> mysql_service 'foo' do
> 15:    initial_root_password 'change me'
> 16:    action [:create, :start]
> 17:  end
> 18:
> ```

My metadata.rb file is below:

> depends 'mysql', '~> 6.0'

I am not sure where this file belongs though. I put it in cookbooks/mysql (same directory where metadata.json is). Not sure if it belongs to cookbooks/mysql/recipes .

I don't know why "mysql_service" isn't being recognized. It is a valid command according to the README.rd file. Does anyone know why this isn't being recognized as a native command?

Comment: I think you printed out **metadata.json** not  **metadata.rb** is in root of your cookbook. Should be depends "mysql", "= 6.0.20" under your version or what OS you support. See mysql cookbook how they do it (they don't have version though)

Comment: Can you add your **metadata.rb** file ? Thanks

Comment: No, you put it inti your's cookbook into root, butI guess you have same name of cookbook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **metadata.rb** should look like this

```
name 'my_cookbook'
maintainer 'Chef Software, Inc.'
maintainer_email 'cookbooks@chef.io'
license 'Apache 2.0'
description 'Provides mysql_service, mysql_config, and mysql_client resources'

version '1.0.0'

depends 'mysql', '~> 6.0'
```

This depends don't go to yours recipe !!

Structure of your repo

```
root/
   cookbooks/
       mysql/
         metadata.rb    
       my_cookbook/
         metadata.rb    # you edit this one
```

Comment: I am confused. What does "This depends don't go to yours recipe !!" mean?

Comment: Also, what does "Structure of your repo cookbooks/ mysql my_cookbook/biliboy" mean? What is "biliboy", is this a chef command? Why is there a space after the "/"? Is this supposed to be one directory or two?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't finish edit, when I lost my connection and cannot edit anymore. I edit it from my iPhone -> not so experienced with phone edits

Comment: This is correct. I put the "depends 'mysql', '~> 6.0'" line in the wrong metadata.rb file. It belongs in the "my_cookbook" directory, not the "mysql" directory. It works now.